# Invalid device symbol error depending on nvcc flags

Tags: cuda, nvcc

Toy program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Matrix side size (they are square).
const int N = 3;
const int num_mats = 14;

// Rotation matrices.
__constant__ float rot_mats_device[num_mats*N*N];

int main() {
  std::vector<float> rot_mats_host(num_mats*N*N);
  for (int i = 0; i < rot_mats_host.size(); i++)
    rot_mats_host[i] = i;

  auto errMemcpyToSymbol = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(rot_mats_device,
                                              rot_mats_host.data(),
                                              sizeof(rot_mats_device));

  if (errMemcpyToSymbol != cudaSuccess) {
    std::cout << "MemcpyToSymbol error: " <<
      cudaGetErrorString(errMemcpyToSymbol) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Compiled with

`nvcc -arch=sm_52 -std=c++11 cuda_invalid_symbol_error.cu -o cuda_invalid_symbol_error`

does not give any error during runtime. However, with

`nvcc -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -std=c++11 cuda_invalid_symbol_error.cu -o cuda_invalid_symbol_error`

it will fail with the message `MemcpyToSymbol error: invalid device symbol`.

Why do the latter instructions for compilation give the runtime error?

Specs: cuda 8.0, Ubuntu 16.04, GeForce GTX 1060 (I know the cc of this card is 6.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do the latter instructions for compilation give the runtime error?

`-arch=sm_xx` is [shorthand](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-steering-gpu-code-generation) for:

```
-gencode arch=compute_xx,code=sm_xx -gencode arch=compute_xx,code=compute_xx
```

In your case, where `xx` is 52, this command embeds both cc 5.2 PTX code (the second `gencode` instance) and cc 5.2 SASS code (the first `gencode` instance).   The SASS code for cc 5.2 will not run on your cc6.1 device, so the runtime JIT-compiles the cc 5.2 PTX code to create an object compatible with your cc 6.1 architecture.  All is happy and everything works.

When you instead compile with:

```
nvcc -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 ...
```

you are omitting the PTX code from the compiled object.  Only the cc 5.2 SASS code is present.  This code will not run on your cc6.1 device, and the runtime has no other options, so a "hidden" error of NO_BINARY_FOR_GPU occurs when the runtime attempts to load the GPU image for your program.  Since no image gets loaded, no device symbol is present/usable.  Since it is not present/usable,  you get the `invalid device symbol` error when you attempt to refer to it using the CUDA runtime API.

If you had performed another CUDA runtime API call prior to this which forced a sufficient or equivalent level of initialization of the CUDA runtime (and checked the returned error code), you would have received a NO_BINARY_FOR_GPU error or similar.   Certainly, for example, if you had attempted to launch a GPU kernel, you would receive that error.  There may be other CUDA runtime API calls that would force an equivalent or sufficient level of lazy initialization, but I don't have a list of those.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the swift answer! Is there a way to force this type of "hidden" errors to be shown during compilation or runtime? I am looking for a way to obtain a specific error message.

Comment: You certainly can't force the error to show at compilation.  It is not known at compile time.  It is only known at runtime.  To force the no binary for GPU error to show at runtime, perform a non-specific CUDA runtime API call such as `cudaSetDevice(0)` early in your program, and do error checking on it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, the call to `cudaSetDevice(0)` returns `cudaSuccess` even when the `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` fails.

Comment: OK this is due to CUDA runtime lazy initialization.  You'll need to find a CUDA runtime API call that forces GPU initialization far enough that the GPU image needs to be loaded.  Given that this may be a moving target (e.g. what works today may not give the same result on a future CUDA version), you might better be advised to organize your error handling in such a way that you can infer a faulty CUDA configuration when you get the `invalid device symbol` error.  Or you can try to hunt around for a benign runtime API call that will actually trigger the error.